# How to create a grouped select from a flat hash of values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am pulling a flat hash of parameters from an external API into my Rails app. I need to present these parameters to the user in a select field.

The hash is formatted as follows:

```
[["Name", "ID", "Category"]]
```

I'd like to present this as a grouped select. But I believe the grouped_select tag takes a hierarchical hash, not a flat hash?

Is there an easy way to restructure this hash into a structured hash? i.e.,

```
['CategoryA', [['Name-A1','ID-A1'],['Name-A2', 'ID-A2']]
```

For reference, I'm currently handling the hash in my controller like this

```
@hash = session["hash"].map { |h| [ h["name"], h["id"], h["category"] ] }
```

and in the view

```
<%= f.select :hash_id, @hash %>
```

This gives me an unordered list of options. How can I group on `h["category"]`?

Thanks for any pointers.

**EDIT**

By the way, I;ve already tried `group_by` as it seemed the obvious way to go. But I'm getting `can't convert String into Integer`. Perhaps I'm not using it correctly?

```
hash.group_by {|h| h["category"] }.map { |h| [ h["name"], h["id"], h["category"] ] }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
hash.group_by {|h| h["category"] }.map { |h| [ h[0], h[1].map{|e| [e["name"],e["id"]]} ] }
```

Comment: OK, that makes a lot of sense now. Thanks for helping! Can you recommend any good sources of information to help with similar issues in the future.